# Capturar multicategorias del $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

Tenia 2 tables en Mysql, una Libros y Otras categorias, y al solo permitir la selección de una categoría este era el código que usaba para actualizar/añadir libros.:

```
if(count($_POST)>0){
$a = new SQLMan();
$a->tablename = "libro";

$numpag = "0";
$year = "0";


$a->in_test = true;
$a->update(array(
    "isbn"=>$a->is_string($_POST["isbn"]),
    "titulo"=>$a->is_string(ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["titulo"]))),
    "subtitulo"=>$a->is_string(ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["subtitulo"]))),
    "anio"=>$a->is_string($year),
    "num_pag"=>$a->is_string($numpag),
    "autor_id"=>$a->is_string($_POST["autor_id"]),
    "editorial_id"=>$a->is_string($_POST["editorial_id"]),
    "categoria_id"=>$a->is_string($_POST["categoria_id"])
    ),"id=".$_POST["id"]);

Core::redir("./index.php?view=ejemplares&id=" . $_POST["id"]);
}
```

He actualizado las tablas para permitir la multicategoria, asi que ahora tengo 3 tablas: libro, categoria, categoriavslibro

En el $_POST al actualizar/añadir sale así:

```
 index.php?isbn=9780723292104&id=131&titulo=1%2C+2%2C+3+With+Peppa&subtitulo=Peppa+Piggg&autor_id=0&editorial_id=0&categoria_id=1&categoria_id=2&categoria_id=4
```

¿Cómo podría sacar las diferentes categorías del $_POST para luego hacer el foreach e insertarlas en la tabla de categoriavslibro? Al tener el mismo nombre, no sabría como hacerlo...

Este sería el HTML del multiselect:

```
   <?php if(count($categorias)>0):?>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">Category:</label>
                <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control kt-select2 select2all" id="categoria_id" name="categoria_id[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <?php foreach($categorias as $categoria):?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $categoria->fields["id"]; ?>" 
                                <?php 
                                if(count($catlib)>0):
                                    foreach($catlib as $cl): ?>
                                        <?php if ($libro->fields["id"] == $cl->fields["libro_id"] && $categoria->fields["id"] == $cl->fields["categoria_id"]): ?>
                                        selected
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach;
                                 else:
                                        if ($categoria->fields["id"] == "0"): 
                                            echo "selected";
                                        else:
                                        endif;
                                endif; ?>

                                >
                                <?php echo $categoria->fields["nombre"];?> 
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo primero es modificar tu pregunta para agregar el HTML, parece que al select le pusiste la opción múltiple, pero no agregaste corchetes al nombre para que lo convierta en array: `<select multiple name="categoria_id[]">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lo primero es modificar tu pregunta para agregar el HTML, parece que
>   al select le pusiste la opción múltiple, pero no agregaste corchetes
>   al nombre para que lo convierta en array:

Añadido los corchetes al name="categoria_id[]" envia los datos en array.

Gracias @Triby